# How would I go about linking an Email URL CTA to an excel sheet

Tags: excel, reactjs, email

I am currently looking at creating an email with a yes/no CTA, I want this data to link through to an excel sheet and populate the answer in a specific column using the email tag to assign the answer to the user column.

Comment: You want tool suggestion or code or anything else? Please be precise.

Comment: Hi Jebin, 

I'm looking for any solution, whether it be code or a tool. I'll be sending this email through SendGrid.